# Search Bar in iPhone 3.0's Built-in Notes.app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

If you drag down list of your notes, search bar will come down. But if you keep dragging it, search bar still stays there right below navigation bar, creating "gutter" between search bar and the first row. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Check out the screenshot here: http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/8094/searchbar6420.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This looks like  a custom drawn frame over the table view. Here is an example of how you can achieve something like that http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html.